# How do you isolate the night periods that fall between days, as the periods you want are not all on the same day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to pick the periods that fall over the night. So, for example, the evening on the 27th of April will run from (let's say) 2017-04-27 18:00 to 2017-04-28 06:30.

I am currently running a for loop that takes the dates out of a Dataframe called data_input

```
for dates in data_input.index:
```

I think that I want to create a mask that will do something with the following terms, but I am not sure exactly how to combine them;

```
data_input.index.date == dates 
data_input.index.hour >18
```

&

```
data_input.index.date == dates+timedelta(days=1)
data_input.index.hour <6
```

So I guess my question how to combine these in the correct way.

For sake of MVE here are the first 40 rows of data_input

```
data_input.head(40)= 
2017-04-27 00:30:00    13.94
2017-04-27 01:30:00    14.88
2017-04-27 02:30:00    15.24
2017-04-27 03:30:00    15.94
2017-04-27 04:30:00    16.42
2017-04-27 05:30:00    16.12
2017-04-27 06:30:00    15.61
2017-04-27 07:30:00    14.96
2017-04-27 08:30:00    14.56
2017-04-27 09:30:00    13.86
2017-04-27 10:30:00    13.24
2017-04-27 11:30:00    13.43
2017-04-27 12:30:00    13.43
2017-04-27 13:30:00    13.12
2017-04-27 14:30:00    13.06
2017-04-27 15:30:00    12.99
2017-04-27 16:30:00    12.92
2017-04-27 17:30:00    12.88
2017-04-27 18:30:00    12.74
2017-04-27 19:30:00    12.72
2017-04-27 20:30:00    12.96
2017-04-27 21:30:00    13.18
2017-04-27 22:30:00    13.55
2017-04-27 23:30:00    14.31
2017-04-28 00:30:00    15.14
2017-04-28 01:30:00    15.77
2017-04-28 02:30:00    15.88
2017-04-28 03:30:00    15.92
2017-04-28 04:30:00    16.51
2017-04-28 05:30:00    17.06
2017-04-28 06:30:00    16.99
2017-04-28 07:30:00    16.42
2017-04-28 08:30:00    15.88
2017-04-28 09:30:00    15.34
2017-04-28 10:30:00    14.92
2017-04-28 11:30:00    14.81
2017-04-28 12:30:00    14.60
2017-04-28 13:30:00    14.29
2017-04-28 14:30:00    14.06
Name: Temperature (°C), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Completely changed solution, you can check it.

Answer (score 1):

So turns out writing the question helped me think through some ways of how to actually do it.

I thought I would share my own solution, just in case anyone else has this issue.

Basically, the solution is to create two masks, one for the night that ay, and another for the early morning the next day and concatenate them together.

```
for dates in data_input.index:
    night_mask = (data_input.index.date+timedelta(days=1) == dates.date())& (data_input.index.hour >18)
    morning_mask = (data_input.index.date == dates.date())& (data_input.index.hour <6)
    night_data = pd.concat( [data_input[night_mask], data_input[morning_mask]] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for dates in data_input.index:
    #remove times (set to 00:00:00)
    d = dates.floor('d')
    #add timedeltas
    today = d + pd.Timedelta(18, unit='h')
    tomorrow = d + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d') + pd.Timedelta(6, unit='h')
    #filtering 
    night_data = data_input.loc[today : tomorrow]
    print (night_data)
```